# If $\int_{a}^{x}f(s)ds\geq0$ for all $x\in\left(a,b\right)$, what about the sign of $\int_{a}^{x}f(a+b-s)ds$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Assume that $f:\left[a,b\right]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function and assume also that $\int_{a}^{x}f(s)ds\geq0$ (or $\int_{a}^{x}f(s)ds\leq0$) for every $x\in(a,b)$. Can I say that also $\int_{a}^{x}f(a+b-s)ds$ does not change sign for every $x\in(a,b)$? It seems to me that it is not true since $$\int_{a}^{x}f(a+b-s)ds=\int_{a}^{b}f(s)ds-\int_{a}^{a+b-x}f(s)ds$$ and so we need more hypotheses for the thesis, for example that $b$ is an extrema for the function $\int_{a}^{x}f(s)ds$, but I'm not able to find a counterexample.

Furthermore, assuming that the claim is indeed not true, what are the weakest hypotheses to obtain the thesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the claim is not true without additional conditions.

Take for example $f(x)=1-2x$ in $[0,2/3]$, then
$$\int_{0}^{x}f(s)ds=\int_{0}^{x}(1-2s)ds=x(1-x)\geq 0 \qquad\text{(red curve)}$$
whereas
$$\int_{0}^{x}f(2/3-s)ds=\int_{0}^{x}(2s-1/3)ds=x(x-1/3) \qquad\text{(blue curve)}$$
which changes its sign at $x=1/3$ (note that $f(1/3)=-1/3<0$).
[image]

More generally, if $F(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f(s)ds>0$ in $(a,b]$ and $f$ is  negative at $c\in (a,b)$ then
$G(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f(a+c-s)ds$ changes its sign in $[a,c]$ because
$G(c)=F(c)>0$ whereas $G(a)=0$ and $G'(a)=f(c)<0$ imply that $G$ is negative in a right neighborhood of $a$.